# Responsive element alignment with MediaQuery - called with a context that does not contain it

Tags: flutter, dart, media-queries

I'm currently designing an app with flutter in dart, and I've been using the [Flutter Speed Dial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial) package trying to align it to the bottom-left of the screen using the marginRight and marginBottom values. marginBottom is easy enough, but the problem with marginRight is that depending on the screen size, the same static value might end up putting the widget at the center, all the way left, or even off the screen depending on the size of the screen.

So I called a mediaQuery to get the screen size and base the widget off that, margin just slightly less than the width of whichever screen it is on, to make the value responsive.

However, it says that MediaQuery is called out of context, even though I'm calling it in SpeedDial, which is under FloatingActionButton of Scaffold, set as home of a MaterialApp like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home:Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
            children: [...]
          ),
        floatingActionButton:
        SpeedDial(
          marginRight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
          marginBottom: 65,
          [...]
          children: [
            SpeedDialChild(
                [...]
            ),
            SpeedDialChild(
              [...]
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

The full error detailed below:

*MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery. No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happed because you do not have a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.*

Thanks in advance, this has been rather frustrating :) any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you are using the wrong context: you should use the context that is a child of `MaterialApp` - in your case the context you are using is a parent of `MaterialApp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue just wrap your main Widget as a `home` of your `MaterialApp` widget, like this:

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(home: YourWidget()),
  );
}
```

And remove the `MaterialApp` widget here

**yourwidget.dart**

```
class YourWidget extends StatelessWidget {

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
            children: [...]
          ),
        floatingActionButton:
        SpeedDial(
          marginRight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
          marginBottom: 65,
          [...]
          children: [
            SpeedDialChild(
                [...]
            ),
            SpeedDialChild(
              [...]
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are losing context as Speeddial is using its own context. to get context back you can use a builder.

Or modify SpeedDial to accept a BuildContext.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home:Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
                children: [...]
              ),
            floatingActionButton: Builder(context) {
           return SpeedDial(
              marginRight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
              marginBottom: 65,
              [...]
              children: [
                SpeedDialChild(
                    [...]
                ),
                SpeedDialChild(
                  [...]
                ),
              ],
            ),
           }
          )
        );
      }
```